# Function not working? Error on execute query

Tags: java, loading

I've an error on the execute query part of the `ResultSet rs = Statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM patient");` line of code. I don't know what is wrong . Hoping for help .

```
JButton btnDb1 = new JButton("J");
btnDb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            ResultSet rs = Statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM patienttable");
            while (rs.next()) {
                 Patient patient = new Patient(rs.getString("patientname"), rs.getString("patientaddress"), rs.getString("patientphone"), rs.getInt("patientid"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" Error ");
        }
    }
});
btnDb1.setBounds(200, 393, 120, 23);
contentPane.add(btnDb1);
```

Comment: What is the error?  Stack traces are helpful.

Comment: it says to rename in file? I click on that and theres still an error

Comment: What I was hoping for was that you'd also include your stack trace in the problem.  We can't begin to tell you what's wrong without that.  It may also help to see your database schema, just to make sure that the columns you're trying to get back actually exist, too. (That *could* be an error as well.)

Answer (score 0):

The below JDBC scaffolding code is missing.

1. Create a connection to the DB using JDBC
2. Create a statement object from the connection
3. Close the connection after it is used.

Google for JDBC tutorials or you can use [this tutorial](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/jdbc/) as a starter.